# Output of TransposeLayer[] is not fully specified, but why?

Tags: neural-networks

So I created and initialized the following NetGraph:

```
faultyNet = NetInitialize@NetGraph[
   {
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[20, "Input" -> {"Varying", 2}],
    TransposeLayer[]
    },
   {
    NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Output"]
    }]
```

which runs successfully. However, when I try to apply it to a test input like this:

```
faultyNet[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

I get the error message: "Cannot evaluate net: output of second layer is not fully specified." I've already tried the following troubleshooting options:

```
TransposeLayer["Output" -> {2, "Varying"}]
TransposeLayer[1<->2]
```

but none of them worked. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: You must specify the dimensions: `TransposeLayer["Input" -> {3, 20}]` will work. Unfortunately `TransposeLayer` cannot have a `"Varying"` output dimension that isn't the first one (as you can see by doing `TransposeLayer["Input" -> {"Varying", 20}]`)